# Get user list from team/group via REST API Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a Service Hook integrated with a Service Bus that triggers when stage is waiting for approval, in the message i get the group assigned for approval and with that info i need to get the mail address of all members of that group.

For now i can only get the details of the group but nothing about the members.

I am also trying to use GraphHttpClient of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services library.

Comment: Hi asimian, any update on this, have you checked my answer? Does it answer your question

Answer (score 0):

If the team you mean is the concept in DevOps service, then you can use the below code to get the team member in C#.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using RestSharp;
using System;

namespace GetTeamMembers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string OrgName = "xxx";
            string wanted_projectname = "xxx";
            string wanted_teamname = "xxx";

            string PAT = "xxx";
            var client1 = new RestClient("https://dev.azure.com/"+OrgName+"/_apis/teams?api-version=6.0-preview.3");
            var request1 = new RestRequest("https://dev.azure.com/"+OrgName+"/_apis/teams?api-version=6.0-preview.3", Method.Get);
            request1.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+PAT);

            var response1 = client1.Execute(request1);
            JObject json_response1 = JObject.Parse(response1.Content);
            int count1 = (int)JObject.Parse(response1.Content)["count"];
            for (int i=0;i<count1;i++) {
                var team_name = (string)json_response1["value"][i]["name"];
                var project_name = (string)json_response1["value"][i]["projectName"];
                var team_id = (string)json_response1["value"][i]["id"];
                var project_id = (string)json_response1["value"][i]["projectId"];
                if (project_name==wanted_projectname&&team_name==wanted_teamname) {
                    var client2 = new RestClient("https://dev.azure.com/"+OrgName+"/_apis/projects/"+project_id+"/teams/"+team_id+"/members?api-version=6.0");
                    var request2 = new RestRequest("https://dev.azure.com/"+OrgName+"/_apis/projects/"+project_id+"/teams/"+team_id+"/members?api-version=6.0", Method.Get);
                    request2.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+PAT);

                    var response2 = client2.Execute(request2);
                    Console.WriteLine(response2.Content);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```